# CSIDL_DESKTOP fails in application that is launched from an service

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application which has the method

shgetspecialfolderpath

to get a folder path. It works fine when I directly run the application. But when I launch the application from a window service, the CSIDL_DESKTOP fails and shgetspecialfolderpath returns error code 2.

Comment: Is your service running as a user that has a desktop folder?

Comment: My service is running under system

Comment: Error code 2 is file not found, which isn't surprising since, as far as I know, system doesn't have a desktop folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: If the service is running as SYSTEM, the profile directory is "%systemroot%\system32\config\systemprofile". This account isn't meant for interactive sessions, so by default it doesn't have a desktop folder. That said, it uses the ".DEFAULT" registry profile, which does have a desktop folder location defined in "HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders". In principle, you could create this folder. In practice, don't do that. Use a token for the desired account with `SHGetKnownFolderPath` or `SHGetFolderPath`, or use the public (common) desktop.

Comment: ULONG sessionID = -1;sessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();if (sessionID != MAXWORD) {ERROR_LOG(<< "Session id" << sessionID);HANDLE hToken = NULL;if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionID, &hToken)){if (hToken != NULL) {PWSTR folderFilePath;// [MAX_PATH];if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_PublicDesktop, KF_FLAG_DONT_VERIFY, hToken, &folderFilePath))

Comment: {INFO_LOG(<< "Getting folder path " << folderFilePath);}else {
ERROR_LOG(<< (SHGetKnownFolderPath failed" << GetLastError());}}
else {ERROR_LOG(<< "User Token Failed " << hToken);}}else {
ERROR_LOG(<< "WTSQueryUserToken Failed" << GetLastError());
}}O/P:SHGetKnownFolderPath failed0

Comment: the above code i tried but failed O/P:SHGetKnownFolderPath failed0

Comment: any one please help me